# 401 Authorization error while Calling Hyperledger composer REST API from nodejs, express API

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I am able to secure hyperledger composer APi with passport jwt token strategy. I am generating token from nodejs application which I am using to get an access token and successfully able to authenticate hyperledger composer API's. Now my issue is that I have to integrate hyperledger APi in frontend application so that logged in user can call these API's. While calling hyperledger API with access token from postman I am able to get results. 
But while calling from nodejs app, getting 401 Authorization error.

Below is my code snippet. Please, help if I am doing something wrong.

```
router.get('/callHyperledgerGetAssets', passport.authenticate('jwt',{session:false}),function(req, res, next){

request.get({
  uri: 'http://localhost:3000/api/SampleAsset',
  headers: { // speciyfy the headers
    "access_token": "s%3AEKuyvKAfMtflyuYfM4cNYtr7HK9lcthr5k5OF69xfi99tE6MABq9fAWS7PPKvFse.5KiNJyilFG92nyc3eteLEiwcP1ys3%2BMGPQB5KuDcF6s"
}

}).pipe(res);
```

});

Comment: The Header should be 'X-Access-Token' and the value you are using looks like the whole cookie, but I think you only need part of it - you can check the length of the token from the /explorer on the REST server and then find out how to extract it from the cookie.

Comment: Thanks Thatcher for response.I am not using complete cookie, i have extracted the access token value from cookie which i am sending in header. Also as you mentioned header name as X-Access-Token , but in the postman while calling hyperledger API, i can autheticate succesfully passing header name as 'access-token'.

Comment: I tried with X-Access-Token' as well, but it is same error

Comment: have you tried adding `{ withCredentials: true }` in your request

Comment: yes i did, but same error.      code below                                       
          request.get({
      uri: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/SampleAsset',
      headers: { 
        "access-token": access_token_value,
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials':true,
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':true
    },
    withCredentials: true

    }).pipe(res);

Comment: One more point i would like to inform is, I tried calling another java service API where it required authorization bearer token as header. With same code changing url and header it worked for JAVA API. But giving problwm with hyperledger API. Code working for java API   router.get('/callJavaAssetsAPI', passport.authenticate('jwt',{session:false}),function(req, res, next){
    request.get({
        uri: 'http://localhost:8077/api/assets',
        headers: { 
          "Authorization": "Bearer <token>
      }
      }).pipe(res); 
  });

Comment: Any suggestions Please